# Change Bookmark Name without Changing TITLE Tag

Tags: title, wp-title

Is it possible to change the name of the bookmarked page when a user adds my page as a bookmark without changing the title tag?

Answer (score 1):

No, title tags are *the* way you set your default titles when bookmarking. It's entirely up to the user whether they want to change it from that default.

Sidenote: This question is also more appropriate for StackOverflow as it doesn't directly relate to WordPress (WordPress Answers is solely for Wordpress-related questions). :-)